# Making buttons turn on LED lights of chipKIT basic I/O shield and Uno32 board

Tags: c, io, pic32

**Question Background**

I have an Uno32 board with a 32-bit MIPS processor and a Basic IO Shield that goes together with it. Among other things, the IO shield has eight LED lights and four push buttons. The below program turns on LED light 1 for the duration that button 1 is pressed. I have commented the code with my interpretation of what each line does and included a supplementary explanation below the code. My actual question is related to the second code snippet, but I start off by presenting this working code in an attempt to motivate my expectations for the second snippet.

```c
#include <pic32mx.h>

/*
 * read from Rx[n]:        (PORTx >> n) & 0x1
 * drive value to Rx[n]:   PORTx = value << n
 *
 * set Rx[n] to output:    TRISx |= 0x...., where only bit n is 0
 * set Rx[n] to input:     TRISx |= 0x...., where only bit n is 1  
 *
 * REn: LED light n+1
 * RFn: Button n+1
 */
int main(void) {
   TRISE = ~0xff; // set RE[7:0] to output, RE[15:8] to input
   TRISF |= 0x2;  // set RF[1] to input

   while(1)
      PORTE = (PORTF >> 1) & 0x1; // drive RF1 to RE0

   return 0;
}
```

The LED lights are wired to glow when driven with a 1 and turn off when driven with a 0. The push buttons are wired to produce a 1 when pressed and a 0 when released. The Uno32 microprocessor organizes groups of GPIOs into ports, and calls these ports RA, RB, RC, RD, RE, RF, and RG. Each port may have up to 16 GPIO pins and is controlled by two registers: TRISx and PORTx, where x is a letter (A-G) indicating the port of interest. The 16 least significant bits of the TRISx register determine whether each pin is an input or an output. When a given bit of the TRISx register is 0, the pin is an output; when it is 1, it is an input. The 16 least significant bits of the PORTx register determine the respective values that are driven to or read from each pin.

Pins 0 through 7 of port E (i.e. `RE0–RE7`) correspond to the eight LED lights. Pin 1 of port F (i.e. `RF1`) corresponds to button 1. I figured out that `RF1` corresponds to button 1 by consulting the reference manuals for the Uno32 board and the IO shield (the relevant tables from the manuals are attached to this message).

[image: reference manuals]

Again, by consulting the reference manual, I believe that `RF2`, `RF3` and `RF4`, correspond to button 2, button 3 and button 4, respectively. (This will be relevant shortly.)

With the above background in mind, let me explain why the above code makes LED light 1 glow for the duration that button 1 is pressed down. The statement `TRISE = ~0xff;` sets pins 0 through 7 of port E (the LED light port) to be outputs. Then, `TRISF |= 0x2;` sets the pin of button 1 to be an input. When the button is pressed, `PORTE = (PORTF >> 1) & 0x1;` drives the input value `1` to the first LED light `RE0` because pressing the button causes `RF1` to become `1`. When the button is released, `PORTE = (PORTF >> 1) & 0x1;` drives the input value `0` to the first LED light `RE0` because `RF1` is `0`. These "mechanisms" explain why the above code makes LED light 1 glow for the duration that button 1 is pressed.

**Question**

Now, using the same reasoning as above, I would expect the below code to make LED light 1 glow for the duration that button 2 is pressed (because I expect that `(PORTF >> 2) & 0x1` gives me the value of `RF2`).

```c
int main(void) {
   TRISE = ~0xff; // set RE[7:0] to output, RE[15:8] to input
   TRISF |= 0x4;  // set RF[2] to input

   while (1)
      PORTE = (PORTF >> 2) & 0x1; // drive RF2 to RE0

   return 0;
}
```

However, the effect of this code is that LED light 1 glows permanently, and that none of the button have any visible effect.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: A quick look at the pinout table for this board shows that the other three buttons are on RD5/RD6/RD7.  RF2 is the serial port receive line.

Comment: @jasonharper Unbelievable, I read the pin # from the wrong column for the other buttons. Your comment completely solves my problem.

Comment: Please write this as an answer and mark it. You can do this for your own question.